# How do I get a stack trace on exception in Blend?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, blend

I'm getting the following error in blend:

[image]

**I am not looking for a fix to this error.** I know what this error is. I have no idea where it is. Is there not a way of getting more information about this exception? I have followed the overloads of the constructor all the way back to the framework and none of it is using a Unity Container. I need to get a stack trace on this exception and I can't figure out how to do that. This is not the first issue I've had with this particular area of WPF designer.

Visual Studio gives me the same useless message.

**Updates**

After following Bolu's suggestion, I was able to get this information:

> System.MissingMethodException occurred
>   Message: A first chance exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Still no stacktrace.

Comment: are you looking for something like this: [DEBUGGING DESIGN-TIME EXCEPTIONS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/expression/archive/2008/06/19/debugging-design-time-exceptions.aspx)?

Comment: That's quite a lot of work for something that should be readily available.

Comment: I broke down and tried your suggestion. I wasn't given a stack trace at all. I posted the information that I did receive above.